# What is this fabric tube that flew off of Chevy Traverse undercarriage?

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, traverse

My cousin was leaving her driveway today when she heard a loud pop and a hiss that made her think that she blew a tire. She found this tube made out of fabric that appears to have shot off from somewhere underneath her Chevy Traverse. It is a little greasy on one end and has little brown beads inside it. Her car seems to run fine without it, but she doesn't want to go anywhere until she identifies what this is.

[image: Tube picture]

Can anyone tell me what this is, where it belongs, and how critical it is to the safe operation of her car?

Comment: It looks like it could be an insulation lining from an AC line or something... I'm not really sure though. Have either of you taken a look underneath to see? There would likely be something clean that it covers since it would have been blocking the dirt & grease. That retaining ring might also go with it, so look for something with a small groove that it would fit in.

Comment: I think @kyle_engineer may be on to something. I’d suggest the beads are desiccant and that the tube and snap ring were part of the accumulator.

Comment: @BlackThorn Does the ac still work?

Comment: @kyle_engineer it was indeed a part of the AC line!